# how to work with RegexIterator::REPLACE mode?

Tags: php, spl

What is wrong in my code:

```
$i = new RegexIterator(
  new ArrayIterator(array(
    'test1'=>'test888', 
    'test2'=>'what?', 
    'test3'=>'test999')),
  '/^test(.*)/',
  RegexIterator::REPLACE);

foreach ($i as $name=>$value)
  echo $name . '=>' . $value . "\n";
```

The iterator is empty, why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please tell us more about your goal/What you want to achieve. The expected result for your example code would be a nice starting point.

Comment: I guess, that according to manual description (RegexIterator::REPLACE
    Replace the current entry or the current key), that it should return all matched keys => values that could be replaced. There are no examples in manual, so, it's unclear how to use it and where to define replacement pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said already, it's a bug in PHP. I reported it to php.net: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50579

Answer (score 1):

If you ommit the operation mode (3rd parameter in your new RegexIterator statement) you'll get the matching values, like so:

```
$array = array('test1' => 'test888', 'test2' => 'what?', 'test3' => 'test999');
$pattern = '/^test(.*)/';

echo '<pre>';
echo "DEFAULT\n";
$arrayIterator = new ArrayIterator($array);
$regexIterator = new RegexIterator($arrayIterator, $pattern);
foreach ($regexIterator as $value) {echo "$value\n";}
echo '</pre>';
```

You can play with the different operation modes, depending on what you want. Go read up on the setMode documentation: http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexiterator.setmode.php

Comment: But if you add $regexIterator->setMode(RegexIterator::REPLACE);
it returns empty iterator (as in question's example), so, it's still unclear how to use REPLACE mode.

Comment: Yes, I can't say I have used the REPLACE mode with success. I would go with preg_replace..

Comment: Alexey, maybe it's a bug in PHP? I have PHP5.3

Comment: hm, well I can confirm the behaviour in PHP5.2.11-0

Comment: anyone with an interest in this topic/issue, maybe it helps to vote for this bug at http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50579

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code

```
$mixedArray=array(
    'tester2',
    'tes1',
    'bad4',
    '2good2',
    '2birds',
    'birds8',
    '8young girls',
    '6 young boys'
);


$ait=new ArrayIterator($mixedArray);
$regexIt=new RegexIterator($ait,'/^(\d+)(\w+)/', RegexIterator::REPLACE);
$regexIt->replacement='$2:$1';

foreach($regexIt as $key=>$value){
    echo $value."<br>";
}
```

**Output**

```
good2:2
birds:2
young:8 girls
```