# PHP SPL RegexIterator removes unmatched elements from array

Tags: php, regex, spl

I have array with some strings and i want to use `RegexIterator` to replace some stuff on matched string but to also leave un-matched strings in array.

Here is my code:

```
    $a = new ArrayIterator(array('LeaveThisInArray','value1', 'value2')); 
    $i = new RegexIterator($a, '/^(value)(\d+)/', RegexIterator::REPLACE); 
    $i->replacement = '$2:$1'; 

    print_r(iterator_to_array($i));
```

And i get this as output:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => 1:value
    [1] => 2:value
)
```

But what i wanted is this:

```
 Array
        (
            [0] => LeaveThisInArray
            [1] => 1:value
            [2] => 2:value
        )
```

Is there any flag i can set or something, because i cant find much in the spl documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think about for this right now is like this:

```
$a = new ArrayIterator(array('LeaveThisInArray','value1', 'value2')); 
$i = new RegexIterator($a, '/^(?:(value)(\d+))?/', RegexIterator::REPLACE); 
$i->replacement = '$2$1'; 

print_r(iterator_to_array($i));
```

Comment: yep, maybe but no semicolons

Comment: what about semicolon? how to add it? I tried same solution but stuck with semicolon.

Comment: well you can set replacement to this '$2:$1'

Comment: but it will add semicolon to the LeaveThisInArray

Comment: I realized that after i posted comment, but i managed it to add semicolon only to matched elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `preg_replace`

sample code:

```
$re = "/^(value)(\\d+)/m";
$str = "LeaveThisInArray\nvalue1\nvalue2";
$subst = '$2:$1';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/wO8eU8/1)

---

Try with `^(value)(\d*)` in your existing code.

Comment: I allready did that way, i just wanted to see if something like this is possible, because i like using SPL, a lot :D

Comment: try last option by making digits as zero or more times.

Comment: true that, ill try messing around with regular expression it self :)

Comment: Read the bug reported [here](http://grokbase.com/t/php/php-bugs/09ctxf6ssc/50579-new-regexiterator-replace-doesnt-work). Read [similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1957069/how-to-work-with-regexiteratorreplace-mode)